# Does magnetism affect thermal conductivity of metals?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermal-conductivity, metals, cooling

If you're going to answer my question I'm sort of asking for some examples or a good graph that shows how it affects different metals if at all. I'm aware that it affects ferro fluid. I've seen mixed results and the internet is no help just to answer such a simple question. I'm guessing that it lowers conductivity like from something I've seen in ferro fluids.

To be clear, I'm asking because I'm interested in cooling systems and I thought after seeing a few things that it might be great if you used ferro fluid or liquid metals and used a magnetic field to push the liquid through a closed loop for a lower viscosity, so to speak, heat dissipation, but that affect if sort of defeated if it also lowers the thermal conductivity of the metal or liquid.

Comment: Here's some info about [magnetic refrigeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration). It talks about the effect of magnetism on heat capacity, but it doesn't mention any effect on thermal conductivity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that's not quiet just what I'm looking for here. I want to use a liquid that has a magnetic influence to be propelled through something at high speeds like ac coolant, but I don't want the magnetism to influence thermal conductivity of the liquid.

Comment: I posted a comment linking to related info. It's not an attempt to answer your question, but I figured the info in that article would be of interest to you, since it does explain a way to do magnetic cooling.

Comment: Yeah I'm a little oriented with that. But I ruled that out for an effective practice because it works well on paper but not actuality.